# How to return a count of fields with a given value in a record?

Tags: delphi, firebird, interbase, ibexpert

I have a database table with the following fields :

```
          ---------------------  
FIELDS :  | H1 | H2 | H3 | H4  
          ---------------------  
VALUES :  | A  | B  | A  | C   
          ---------------------
```

For a given record (row), I would like to count the number of fields with a value of `A`.  In the above, for example, there are two fields with a value of `A`, so the expected result would be : `2`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Add a calculated field to your dataset and calculate the sum of columns A1..A4 in the dataset's OnCalcFields event.  Since the values you quote are all the character 'H', it's not clear what you would consider their sum as characters is, nor as an integer.

Comment: example: Sum (A1+A2+A3+A4) as Total , = 4 if no null having

Comment: While it is clear to you what you are doing (I hope), we do not have a clue what is going on. so dear asker add something useful to your question, a code sample maybe, a way to fill the dataset if any, or maybe and I mean maybe some more explanation to the situation you are having. and thank you in advance for your understanding of the situation.

Comment: Do you want to count how cells contain H?

Comment: You can't *sum* letters in any column. You sum numbers, not letters. You can count them, though. Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying to answer the question **from a database point of view**.

You have a table with one or more rows and every row has in the four columns either an 'A' or something else. For a given row (or for many rows) you want to get the number of columns that have an 'A' in it.

As one commenter pointed out you can't sum letters but you can check whether or not a value is the one you are looking for and then count this occurence as a 1 or 0. Finally sum *those* values and return the sum.

```sql
SELECT (CASE H1 WHEN 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
       (CASE H2 WHEN 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
       (CASE H3 WHEN 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
       (CASE H4 WHEN 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS number_of_a
FROM   name_of_your_table;
```

For your example row this will return:

```
NUMBER_OF_A
===========
          2
```

If you have more than one row you'll get the number of As for every row.

Answer (score 0):

I test this it work **Thanx for help**.

```
 SELECT count(H1) + count(H2) + count(H3) + count(H4) + count(H5) + 
count(H6) + count(H7) + count(H8) as TOT
from Table T
where T.H1 = 'A' or T.H2 = 'A' or T.H3 = 'A' or T.H4 = 'A' 
or T.H5 = 'A' or T.H6 = 'A' or T.H7 = 'A' or T.H8 = 'A'
group by T.ID
order by 1 DESC
```

Other solution ...